# using javascript and mvc3 to get list and populate table without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Im trying to figure out how to dynamically populate a table without refreshing the page. Im using mvc3.
Based on a selection from a dropdownlist, the table has to be populated.
How do I in mvc3 make a httpget so I can retreive a list based on the input from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below link for a good article for on how you can make calls to the server through client side code :

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views

Comment: Great! Seems like its something I can use. Thanks.